# How to see what version of Binutils is on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, binutils

I have searched, but not found an option that tells me what version of binutils I have on My Ubuntu. Or at least I don't know how to interpret it.

`gcc -v` - tells nothing about binutils

`ld -v`  - tells me `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24`. Does this means that I have binutils 2.24?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, with `ld -v` you can view the version of binutils (in your case is 2.24)

Answer (score 10):

I tested it only with the Debian 8, but I think it must be working with other Debian-based operation systems (Ubuntu, Mint, other).

---

**dpkg -l | grep binutils**

```
$ dpkg -l | grep binutils
ii  binutils                                     2.25-5+deb8u1                        amd64        GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities
```

---

**apt-cache policy binutils**

```
$ apt-cache policy binutils
binutils:
  Installed: 2.25-5+deb8u1
  Candidate: 2.25-5+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.25-5+deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.25-5 0
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

---

**apt-cache show binutils** (stripped)

```
$ apt-cache show binutils
Package: binutils
Version: 2.25-5+deb8u1
Installed-Size: 20566
Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: binutils-gold (<< 2.20.51.20100415), binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (<< 2.23.52.20130612-1+3), binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (<< 2.23.52.20130612-1+3)
Provides: binutils-gold, elf-binutils
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
Suggests: binutils-doc (>= 2.25-5+deb8u1)
..............................
```

---

**ld --version**

```
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25
```

---

**ar --version**

```
$ ar --version
GNU ar (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sh <(dpkg -L binutils | awk '/bin\// {print $0 " --version"}') | \
grep Binutils | sort -u | column -t
```

This gets all the binaries in the binutils packages and queries each one with its --version parameter. I echo an empty string for those that expect input in the terminal.